# Composer version pattern not working

Tags: composer-php

In my composer I've the following version definition of a module:

```
"my-module": "1.*"
```

Everything was working fine until I've changed the module tag version to **1.0.10**.

The strange thing is that composer is always loading **1.0.9**.
I could change the pattern to `"1.0.*"`, but I can't find any info why `"1.*"` is not working.

btw. *I'm using Composer version 1.4.1*

Comment: which command did you run? if there is a composer.lock file (which you should include in your repo) then you need to run `composer update my-module`. and i would not use * for version constraints anymore. i would guess your application needs this bugfix, so better use `"my-module": "^1.0.10"`

Comment: I deleted the composer.lock and the vendor folder and run `composer install`.
Notice that if I change the pattern to `"1.0.*"` it works, but `"1.*"` doesn't work.

Comment: first you should not simply delete composer.lock there is a reason for it. and do not use the asterisk wildcard anymore. it does not prevent that in future versions of your application your version is going down again to 1.0.8 or similiar due to other packages dependencies, when you delete composer.lock you might even miss this. have you tried using `"^1.0.10"`? i think "1.*" is even invalid, see documentation: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#wildcard-version-range- also this might be interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGD7G8-ccqs&t=1230

Comment: @NormanM By deleting the composer.lock and the vendor folder I was trying to simulate a brand new setup. `"1.*"` is valid but doesn't seems to work correctly and as I wrote earlier it works if I change it to `"1.0.*"`. I just wanted to know whether this is a composer issue or is a documented behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To find out why a particular version is not updated, you can run `composer why-not package/name version`, and Composer will list all dependencies that prevent the installation of that particular version.

I have a feeling that in your case you will detect another package that you did not consider yet.